# Capture multiple photos using camera2 captureBurst() function

Tags: android, android-camera

How can I capture multiple photos using `camera2` `captureBurst()` function. On Stack Overflow I have not found proper answers. If it is possible write an example, please.

Comment: What is your starting point? Have you looked at samples such as https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic ? Where are you running into issues?

Comment: I am using that example which you mention  and tried to capture multiple photos by captureBurst function but it captures only one photo

Comment: How do you know only one photo is captured? No capture result? No second image from the imagereader? Did you increase the imagereader's max count?